# MRTK Unity Android Scrolling by touch input is too slow

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, input, mobile, mrtk

I am trying to make Scrolling Object Collection from [MRTK Unity](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) work with Android.
The problem is, that scrolling is just too slow. When I swipe across the whole screen the objects in the list barely move.
If I look at the collection, touch the screen, and then move my phone in the direction I want to scroll, everything works fine.
But that is not how I want users to scroll.
Any ideas how to make the touch behave the same way/have the same impact as moving the phone?